# Why is std::set allowing me to insert repeated (non-unique) custom elements?

Tags: c++

I need to create a collection of custom items that:

1. Are ordered by priority
2. Can't have repeated names.

In this example, I am using **std::set** with an overloaded **operator<( )**.As far as I know, **std::set** uses the **operator<( )** both for ordering and for uniqueness check. But my code is failing, as I am able to insert items with repeated names:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>



struct Item
{
    std::string name;
    int priority;
};



bool operator<( const Item& a, const Item& b ) 
{
    // Always returns false if names are equal.
    // Set should consider elements equal when a < b is false and b < a is also false.
    if( a.name == b.name )
        return false;

    return ( a.priority < b.priority );
}



int main()
{
    Item a  { "a", 3000 };
    Item b  { "b", 4000 };
    Item c  { "c", 2000 };
    Item a2 { "a", 5000 };


    std::set<Item> pool;


    pool.insert( a );
    pool.insert( b );
    pool.insert( c );
    pool.insert( a2 );


    for( const auto& item : pool )
        std::cout << item.name << ": " << item.priority << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this in onlinegdb.com gives me the result below.

Both elements with the name "a" are inserted into the **std::set**.

```
c: 2000
a: 3000
b: 4000
a: 5000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Should I use a different container?

**EDIT:**

Changing the insert order makes the code work as expected.

```
    pool.insert( a );
    pool.insert( a2 );
    pool.insert( b );
    pool.insert( c );
```

Correctly results in:

```
c: 2000
a: 3000
b: 4000
```

Comment: You're using a `set` when you want a `map`.

Comment: These items are all distinct, so it's perfectly OK.

Comment: @Eljay How so? If I use std::map, the key would have to be the item name. As such, I can't order by priority, since std::map can only items by keys, and not by values.

Comment: Give some very deep though to your comparator, because i'm not whatsoever convinced it is fully compliant to exhibit the strict weak ordering which is *mandated* by the standard library for proper functionality when storing items in a `std::set`. If variation of insertion order into the set for what you claim are distinct elements results in inconsistent (read: not identical) result sets, you can bet your last dollar your comparator is broken, and as such so is your usage for `std::set`

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't disagree, but I've looked at this for a few minutes and I can't quite say *why* it's broken.

Comment: I "cleaned" the operator<( ) code to make it more explicit. I still can't see what's wrong, and I'd really appreciate some criticism here.

Comment: Yeah... that down vote was really unfortunate. As far as I read about std::set, if considers two itens equal when reflexive operator<( ) returns false... and I am really lost here about this behaviour. Just tossing my question into the bin was just... bad.

Comment: @MarkRansom the ordering is broken when the names are equivalent. When that happens the result is *always* false. That would play out fine if this were a test of *equality*, but it isn't. SWO as you are keenly aware holds the property that if if neither (a < b) nor (b < a) are true, then a == b is implicitly true. Further, if (a < b) and (b < c) are true then (a < c) must be true. Neither of those are proper by the OPs comparator.

Comment: To clarify, `Item`s with different names, but same priority should be considered equivalent, right?

Comment: @cigien Nope. Items with same names are considered equivalent, independent of priority. Priority only matters for ordering, so that the itens with highest priority are always at the end (or begining) of the container.

Comment: Ah, I see, then I don't think you can write a comparator for `set` that satisfies this. I'm not entirely sure though.

Comment: @WagnerVolanin do you always access elements only by highest/lowest priority? I mean is this a queue that you take highest priority elements out of it?

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks.  I knew about a < b or b < a, but never considered a < b < c.

Comment: @Slava Yes, I only access elements by highest priority. I was considering using std::priority_queue, but I also have the restriction that I can't have elements with repeated names, which std::priority_queue don't satisfy.

Comment: @WagnerVolanin ok I will update my answer with STL container

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Your comparison function fails to impose a strict weak ordering. That is a requirement of `Compare` concept that is a requirement of the standard set. Violating that requirement results in undefined behaviour.

A strict weak ordering relation must transitive (*For all x, y, z in S, if x < y and y < z then x < z*). Your comparison function does not have this property.

> So, how does std::set determines that the elements are unique?

Equivalence is determined by `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`.

> Can I override that to just check the item names?

Only way to affect the equivalence relation is to change the comparison function. There is no way to separate the uniqueness constraint from the ordering constraint with the standard set.

> Should I use a different container?

Yes.

> Any suggestions how I can solve this with the STL containers?

None of the standard containers are suitable. What you need is a multi-index container. Boost library collection has an implementation.

Comment: Aah, transitivity is broken. Nice catch. The comparator is correctly asymmetric though it seems.

Comment: Best explanation up to now. So, how does std::set determines that the elements are unique? Can I override that to just check the item names? I read it was by testing a < b and b < a both to be false, but this clearly goes against your explanation.

Comment: @cigien I've removed that until I find a counter example. I may have gotten something mixed up with my intuition.

Comment: @WagnerVolanin See edit. You've read correctly, and what you've read is not against my explanation.

Comment: @eerorika Any suggestions how I can solve this with the STL containers?

Comment: @WagnerVolanin None of the standard containers is suitable.

Answer (score 3):

You comparator does not satisfy [Strict Weak Ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Axiomatizations) which is required by `std::set` in particular **transitivity**:

```
> For all x, y, z in S, if x < y and y < z then x < z (transitivity)
```

but for your comparator if `x` and `z` has the same name and priority of `x` is less than `y`, then `x` < `z` would be false.

If you need elements to have unique names and be sorted on priority I would suggest [boost.multiindex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) with hashed unique index on name and sorted non unique index on priority.

To implement priority queue you can use multiple STL containers:

```
struct priority_queue {
    using list = std::list<Item>;

    using cmp = std::function<bool(list::const_iterator,list::const_iterator)>;

    using name_idx = std::set<list::const_iterator,cmp>;
    using priority_idx = std::multiset<list::const_iterator,cmp>;

    list m_list;
    name_idx m_nameidx;
    priority_idx m_priorityidx;

    priority_queue() :
        m_nameidx( []( list::const_iterator it1, list::const_iterator it2 ) {
            return it1->name < it2->name;
        } ),
        m_priorityidx( []( list::const_iterator it1, list::const_iterator it2 ) {
            return it1->priority < it2->priority;
        } ),
    {
    }

    bool push( Item itm )
    {
        m_list.push_front( std::move( itm ) );
        if( !m_nameidx.insert( m_list.begin() ).second ) {
            m_list.erase( m_list.begin() );
            return false;
        }
        m_priorityidx.insert( m_list.begin() );
        return true;
    }
    Item pop()
    {
        auto it = *( priority_idx.begin() );
        m_priorityidx.erase( priority_idx.begin() );
        m_nameidx.erase( it );

        auto ret = std::move( *it );
        m_list.erase( it );
        return ret;
    }
};
```

I did not try to compile or validate the code, but it should be enough to express the idea. For optimization purpose you may want to store iterator to name index inside `Item` object currently it would lookup for O(logN) based on string on every pop. Alternatively you may want to use `std::unordered_set` for name index and provide hashing function and equality operator instead of less than comparator.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is for an embedded project that doesn't have boost.

Comment: @WagnerVolanin If you cannot have boost, then implement the container yourself.

Comment: @WagnerVolanin I believe boost.multiinex is "headers only" library, so you can just copy them to your project and use.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I was glancing to quickly at your less than operator in my original response.

The problem is that your less than operator does not return a proper order for Items with different names. `(a, *) < (b, *)` and `(b, *) < (a, *)` are both false which should only be the case if the two items are identical (as in `x < x`) which they are not.  Therefore the internal structure of the set is not correct since ordering relationship is incorrect and the result is quite random.

The problem is you want your `<` operator to do two things at the same time.  The set uses the ordering to identify duplicates for that you need to order by the name.  At the same time you want to order by the priority such that higher priorities appear first.

I guess you need something like boost.multiindex as suggest by @Slava.  If you cannot use that, you may have to implement your own data structure.  Maybe you can build on top of the std::priority_queue.

For completeness reason, my original response where I did not spot that `<` is broken:

In your example the items `(a, 3000)` and `(a, 5000)` may have the same name, but they are not the same.  Therefore, you can insert multiple such items into the set.

By your definition of the `<` operator `Item("a", 3000)` is less than `Item("a", 5000)`.  The set does not know the composition of your item.

Comment: This is not true. If I do pool.insert(a2) just after pool.insert(a), it works as expected. The std::set container should consider both items equal when a < b is false and b < a is also false (which happens in my code).

Comment: @WagnerVolanin • it works as "expected" only because the `operator<` is broken.

Comment: I just looked at your less than operator in more detail.  It does not work correctly.

Comment: @Tom I "cleaned" the operator<( ) code to make it more explicit. I still can't see what's wrong, and I'd really appreciate some criticism here. As I answered earlier, I can't use map as you suggested, because it wouldn't allow me to order items by priority (value), only by name (key).